# How do I count by month using POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find out how many times a value has been entered using the date format. I'm also using postgresql amazon redshift. The error I'm receiving is

`"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
'2012-01-01' AND r.requested_at < '2012-01-31' END) AS la..."`

```
SELECT u.user_id,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN r.stopped_at > '2012-01-01' THEN r.stopped_at < '2012-01-31' END) AS last_stop_dt
```

Comment: use `SUM(CASE WHEN r.stopped_at > '2012-01-01' AND r.stopped_at < '2012-01-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` instead

Comment: that query is returning "0" for the month of Jan. If it helps, the actual date format is 2012-05-28 08:16:42 (Year, Month, Date and Hour,Minute,Second)

Comment: According to your format it is May, not Jan

Comment: Correct, I just used that specific date to show how the date format is set-up, I'm not using that actual date in the query.

Comment: So I used your query but replaced COUNT with SUM and that ended working. Thanks @Mathemats!

Comment: @AllenM Dude, that was your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your select is missing the `from Table`.

But you can use a select like this to count by month if the r.stopped_at is a date

```
select u.user_id, to_char(r.stopped_at, 'MM'), count(to_char(r.stopped_at, 'MM')) 
from User u, R r
group by u.user_id, to_char(r.stopped_at, 'MM')
```

if its a timestamp field you must use:

```
select u.user_id, extract(month from r.stopped_at), count(extract(month from r.stopped_at)) 
from User u, R r
group by u.user_id, extract(month from r.stopped_at)
```